# Laravel testing redirect from function

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

If I have a function that checks to see if a string is numeric and redirects back if it is not but does nothing if it is ie

```
function check_numeric(string $param) {
    if(!is_numeric($param)) {
        return Redirect::back()->with('Failed', 'Number!');
    }
}
```

How would I test this in PHPUnit? I have tried to use `assertRedirect` but I am not sure of how to implement it (if it is even possible)

To be clear. The `check_numeric()` function is a standalone function that is imported into controllers to be used by the different controller classes. The fucntion itself does not have a class nor a route.

What I would like to do is test the function directly without its use in a  controller or route.

I can test the `pass` cases by doing:

```
$this->assertNull(check_numeric('1')); // does what I want!!
```

However I would also like to directly check the `fail` cases with something like

```
$previousUrl = '/';

$this->from($previousUrl)->(check_numeric('five'))->assertRedirect($previousUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not automatic way to check if it's redirecting back, but you can build it.

To approaches comes to mind.

All samples assumed under **phpunit**, test extending `Tests\TestCase`;

1 - Check the URL before you make the request

```php
$currentUrl = "/";

$response = $this->post('check-number', "five" );

$response->assertRedirect($currentUrl);
```

2 - Validate the message you're sending back when the validation fails.

```php
$response = $this->post('/check-number', "five" );

$this->followRedirects($response)->assertSee('Failed');
```

**YourController.php**

```php
function check_numeric(string $param) {
    if(!is_numeric($param)) {
        return Redirect::back()->with('Failed', 'Number!');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```php
 Route::post('/check-number', 'App\Http\Controllers\YourControllerController@check_numeric');
```

In the other hand, responding to your previous question, if you want to test the function directly, you have to go with what you're expecting, in this case you're not returning anything if everything is OK, so the way to go on that case would be:

```php
$this->assertNull(app('App\Http\Controllers\YourControllerController')->check_numeric("five"));
```

This would fail, if you pass a number it would pass.

Doesthat help?

Comment: Hi Hector, what is the syntax for actually testing the function `check_numeric()`. I believe what you have written will for checking a route to a controller class?

Comment: Hello @matt, since you asked about the redirection, I focused on that, but I updated the answer to respond about testing the function.

Comment: sorry, I think that I was not perfectly clear with my question so I have edited it. The function is a standalone function that is imported for use by different controllers. I want to test it without calling a route or accessing a controller. Sorry for the confusion and I appreciate your time

Comment: No problem, I'll try to help you anyway.